# Proper way to get a generics type argument

Tags: java, generics, interface, generic-type-argument

The following code gets the first type parameter class declared generically in the interface `SomeGenericInterface` which gets concretely implemented in the class `SomeClass`.

This code actually works.

The question is: Does it work in any case, i.e. are the following two Class methods:

- `getInterfaces()`
- `getGenericInterfaces()`

guaranteed to always have the same number of elements with the same respective order of the interfaces returned by these methods?

Or is there some safer way to do this?

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

Class clazz = SomeClass.class;

Class classes[] = clazz.getInterfaces();
Type types[] = clazz.getGenericInterfaces();
ParameterizedType found = null;

for (int i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
   if (  classes[i] == SomeGenericInterface.class) {
      found = (ParameterizedType) types[i];
      break;
   }
}
if (found == null) {
     return null;
}
Class firstType = (Class) found.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29) for both methods states:

> If this object represents a class, the return value is an array
>   containing objects representing all interfaces implemented by the
>   class. The order of the interface objects in the array corresponds to
>   the order of the interface names in the implements clause of the
>   declaration of the class represented by this object.

so the answer to both your questions is yes, the same number of elements and in the same order.

Comment: comming from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250619/classgetinterfaces-and-classgetgenericinterfaces-return-arrays-of-differin I must warn that this assumption holds only for javac compiled code. If the class comes from somewhere else all bets are off

Answer (score 0):

> Does it work in any case

No, but not for the reasons you suspect. It will only work if the class implements the interface directly (as opposed to inherting the interface from a super class), and specifies a concrete type for the type parameter (as opposed to using a type parameter, as in the following example).

```
class CounterExample<T> implements Interface<T> {}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was actually aware of that; the question actually was, whether the order of the interfaces contained in classes[] and types[] is guaranteed to be the same for a concrete class implementing the interface directly (ok that was not so clearly stated, sorry) with a concrete type parameter. As rsp pointed out: Yes.