# Class#getInterfaces() and Class#getGenericInterfaces() return arrays of differing length

Tags: java, scala

If you take the class `scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction` from Scala 2.10.2 (I did not check other versions) and compare the output of `AbstractPartialFunction.class.getInterfaces()` and `AbstractPartialFunction.class.getGenericInterfaces()` you may notice, that the results do not match. The generic Interfaces are `scala.Function1<T1, R>` and `scala.PartialFunction<T1, R>`, while getInterfaces() only returns `scala.PartialFunction`. Form the scala documentation I can see that the generic information is right, because PartialFunction is a Function1.

The javadoc for getInterfaces says:

> If this object represents a class, the return value is an array containing objects representing all interfaces implemented by the class. The order of the interface objects in the array corresponds to the order of the interface names in the implements clause of the declaration of the class represented by this object.

and getGenericInterfaces has the exact same text.

From that (and from other texts, including stackoverflow information) I would conclude that order and length of the arrays are equal. Only this is not the case here. Why?

I was able to reproduce this with several java7 and java8 so far, didn't try java6 or even java5.

**EDIT:**

The javap output for AbstractPartialFunction (only the header of course) is:

```
Compiled from "AbstractPartialFunction.scala"
public abstract class scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction<T1, R> implements scala.Function1<T1, R>, scala.PartialFunction<T1, R>`
```

Using the asm lib and the Textifier there I can see this header information:

```
// class version 50.0 (50)
// access flags 0x421
// signature <T1:Ljava/lang/Object;R:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1<TT1;TR;>;Lscala/PartialFunction<TT1;TR;>;
// declaration: scala/runtime/AbstractPartialFunction<T1, R> implements scala.Function1<T1, R>, scala.PartialFunction<T1, R>
public abstract class scala/runtime/AbstractPartialFunction implements scala/PartialFunction
```

plus a ScalaSigAttribute. Of course I did not show the methods in both cases

Comment: what about the magic "generic" word?

Comment: I am aware that one has generics information and the other not. That is not the question

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the type with javap?

Comment: I attached javap and asm output of the class header... I can see a difference there... Is this really supposed to be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Compiled from AbstractPartialFunction.scala (version 1.6 : 50.0, super bit)
// Signature: <T1:Ljava/lang/Object;R:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1<TT1;TR;>;Lscala/PartialFunction<TT1;TR;>;
@scala.reflect.ScalaSignature(bytes="some bytes...")
public abstract class scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction implements scala.PartialFunction {
```

The signature of the type is roughly equivalent to this Java declaration:

```
class AbstractPartialFunction implements PartialFunction, Function1 {}
```

*PartialFunction* extends *Function1*:

```
// Compiled from PartialFunction.scala (version 1.6 : 50.0, no super bit)
// Signature: <A:Ljava/lang/Object;B:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1<TA;TB;>;
@scala.reflect.ScalaSignature(bytes="some bytes...")
public abstract interface scala.PartialFunction extends scala.Function1 {
```

Here is [the structure of a Java class file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1):

```
ClassFile {
    u4             magic;
    u2             minor_version;
    u2             major_version;
    u2             constant_pool_count;
    cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
    u2             access_flags;
    u2             this_class;
    u2             super_class;
    u2             interfaces_count;
    u2             interfaces[interfaces_count];
    u2             fields_count;
    field_info     fields[fields_count];
    u2             methods_count;
    method_info    methods[methods_count];
    u2             attributes_count;
    attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
}
```

The interfaces the type implements are stored in the constant pool and recorded by references in the *interfaces* array:

The [class signature is stored as an attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.9) in the *attributes* array:

> The `Signature` attribute records generic signature information for any class, interface, constructor or member whose generic signature in the Java programming language would include references to type variables or parameterized types.

So here's my educated guess about what is happening:

- `Class.getInterfaces()` returns the values from the *interfaces* array
- `Class.getGenericInterfaces()` builds its return value using the type signature
- the Scala compiler removes *Function1* from the *interfaces* array because *PartialFunction* extends *Function1*
- the Scala compiler preserves the type signature as-is

This behavior is different to the byte code that the Oracle JDK produces from equivalent Java sources but It's obviously passing all the checks the JVM makes when loading classes.

Comment: I can almost accept the answer, but the Javadoc says that **all** interfaces implemented by this class appear in the array. This is not the case here. Or do I take the javdoc to literally here? It speaks of the implements clause extra. Next thing is... why is Function1 in the generic signature?. And two more things... just because the code passes the Verifier, does not mean it is valid bytecode and produced as intended by the JVM guys. Plus, I don't think scala.reflect.ScalaSignature is of any importance for Java and the two methods here.

Answer (score 1):

So to fully answer my question... I will still accept the other though...

The returned arrays differ in length, because the generics signature and the normal signature in bytecode don't match. I doubt it is legal to do so, but since it seems it is unchecked there is no one to complain. Answers like this one: [Proper way to get a generics type argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553423/proper-way-to-get-a-generics-type-argument) though will leave a wrong impression for cases from outside the javac generated world.

Furthermore, **all** interfaces means not all in the hierarchy, only the ones directly implemented. In Java that would be, what is found in the implements clause. The javadoc for the android version of Class uses a different wording for a good reason. Anyway, as already said, it can differ - especially if the class is not from javac.